# Related Salesforce Objects not showing in Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect

I have created a Journey which uses Salesforce Data as my entry event. When I am setting up the Filter Criteria, some of my related objects are not shown.

All objects used are synced from Salesforce so my understanding is that the relationships are already configured, I have verified this in the Data Designer.

Any ideas why some related objects might not be shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Quote from Eliot's data handbook, hope it helps:

Salesforce Objects use a different relationship model to
Marketing Cloud. Objects can have multiple relationships with
other Objects, whereas Contact Builder only supports a single
relationship between Objects in an Attribute Group. When
Objects are imported into Synchronized Data Extensions, field
relationships are remapped using a predetermined priority
based on, first, predefined standard Object relationships, then
standard relationship fields (in alphabetical order), and finally,
custom relationship fields (in alphabetical order).

See more here: ttps://www.getstride.com/datahandbook

Comment: Do you have any other documentation (preferably from Salesforce's help documentation) that back this up? This sounds plausible but I don't have access to that data handbook to confirm.

Comment: Try here: https://gofile.io/?c=lTqIwR

Comment: @zuzannamj sorry, but what does this actually mean to OG question, as I'm facing the same issue? How can I be sure what object will be visible in Journey Builder? And if I can't see it does this mean I need to change a data relationship or do I need to forgo using the SF Data Entry and resort to the exhausting SQL Data Extension method instead?